# Should I keep whitespace in my appended string or change to %20?

Tags: php, performance, security

On my site, POSTs are typically handled as follows:

```
$login_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_SESSION['login_id']);

if (isset($_POST['var'])) {
    $var = strip_tags(trim($_POST['var']));
    $sql=mysqli_query($cxn, "UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $var)."' WHERE login_id = '$login_id'");
    if (!$sql) {
        $M = 'There was a problem with the server';
    }
}
header('Location: page.php?message='.$M);
}
```

However, I notice the location I am sent to (in the case of a problem with the query) contains %20 in place of white space (not unexpected):

```
http://www.mysite.com/page.php?message=There%20was%20a%20problem%20with%20the%20server
```

I checked my error_log and noticed that it doesn't report my lack of use of %20 as even a notice or warning. For performance/security/etc. (my site contains dozens of these strings), is there any reason that I should include the %20 in my string = $M that is passed to page.php?

Comment: I'd say this is just your browser handling the bad string. You should really be using `?message=' . urlencode($M)`

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest you read this ~ [MySQLi - Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To directly answer your question, you should be URL encoding any value used in an URL, eg

```
header('Location: page.php?message=' . urlencode($M));
exit;
```

The spaces are probably being handled by your browser but you would run into real problems if your string contained something like an ampersand (`&`)

Comment: @ChemBlob9999 : mark Phil's answer as correct because he answered in comments first.

Comment: I know....SO informed me I needed to wait 5 minutes before I could mark it as accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

When creating URL, you should escape them first. As @Phil said, `urlencode($M)` is the best choice.

```
$login_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $_SESSION['login_id']);

if (isset($_POST['var'])) {
    $var = strip_tags(trim($_POST['var']));
    $sql=mysqli_query($cxn, "UPDATE table1 SET column1 = 
    '".mysqli_real_escape_string($cxn, $var)."' WHERE login_id = '$login_id'");
    if (!$sql) {
        $M = 'There was a problem with the server';
    }
}
header('Location: page.php?message='.urlencode($M));
```